# Android - Marshmallow - Webview Library

Tags: android, webview

Anyone know of a solid webview library which implements the Marshmallow runtime permission model? Must support camera access.

I found these examples: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples, but they are over 2 years old and do not implement the runtime permission model.

So then I found various libs like this: https://github.com/teegarcs/Runtime_Permissions/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/captech/runtime/MainActivity.java which do implement the runtime model, but do not use webview.

Comment: Hey thanks for the anon downvote and vote to close... it is a legitimate software question.

Comment: "it is a legitimate software question" -- yes, but it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Quoting [the site documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: I understand what you are getting at @CommonsWare. I've seen those posts, "Hey which Framework is better, Symfony or Zend", which will result in biased responses. In this case I am actually looking for concrete code examples of a webview framework that works with M and it's runtime permissions.

Comment: did you try with "WebChromeClient"?

Comment: @SachinS: WebChromeClient is the de facto standard for webview, that's not what the question is asking. I am looking for concrete code example demonstrating how to incorporate runtime permissions for camera access in conjunction with a webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I had to jump down this rabbit hole and code it out myself. I will be submitting this to github as a public (open source) repo over the next few days as I work in a better webview api (XWalk). But for now, here is working code for a webview which asks for runtime perms for camera or gallery access based on user selected option.

https://gist.github.com/digitalprecision/735820df14f696fc2c6c8b251b2b05d6

Answer (score 0):

Use 
[Crosswalk Project for Android](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html)

Using WebChromeClient  you can check your permission, if app needs camera acccess .

```
webView= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.main_webView);
webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
         //Check permission here
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Ya I tried this one... but couldn't find any working examples of how to incorporate it with camera, only thing I could find was incorporating cordova, which I do not want to do.

Comment: Another option is you should check permission before loading webview

Comment: Why would I do that? It would be a bad UX to request camera permissions for someone who wants to use 80% of the rest of the app that requires no permissions.

Comment: You don't need Cordova. You just need to throw in a compile dependency.

Answer (score 0):

did you try [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)? This is top of the android native webview..it has access to most of the hardware/Camera with permission model.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10120

Comment: No, I don't want to introduce yet another api.